# creating row index based on time difference in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that looks like:

```
player  event  diff
  A       x     NA
  A       y     2
  A       z     240
  A       w     3
  A       x     9
  B       x     NA
  B       y     3
  B       z     120
  C       x     NA
  C       x     8
```

What I did to get this was to group by the player column and take the difference between time events, hence the NA's for diff column whenever a new player has an event.

What I want to do is to partition the data into player specific interactions that are within a few minutes of each other (say a cutoff of diff = 20). What I want in the end is to have:

```
     player  event  diff   interaction
      A       x     NA         1
      A       y     2          1
      A       z     240        2
      A       w     3          2
      A       x     9          2
      B       x     NA         1
      B       y     3          1
      B       z     120        2
      C       x     NA         1
      C       x     8          1
```

So basically the interactions are grouped based on having the same player and the difference being less than 20, otherwise a new interaction is started. A new interaction is also started if an NA is present. I'm not really sure how to do this in a fast/efficient way as I've got a large data set with many players. My preference is for a `dplyr` solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace NA with 0(or other number that is below your threshold) using `coalesce` in the diff column and do a cumsum on the `diff >= 20` condition, which will give a distinct id whenever `diff` exceed some threshold:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(player) %>% 
       mutate(interaction = cumsum(coalesce(diff, 0L) >= 20) + 1)

# Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
# Groups: player [3]

#    player  event  diff interaction
#     <fctr> <fctr> <int>       <dbl>
# 1       A      x    NA           1
# 2       A      y     2           1
# 3       A      z   240           2
# 4       A      w     3           2
# 5       A      x     9           2
# 6       B      x    NA           1
# 7       B      y     3           1
# 8       B      z   120           2
# 9       C      x    NA           1
# 10      C      x     8           1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `base R` to get the expected output

```
df1$interaction <- with(df1, ave(diff, player, FUN = function(x) 
                        cumsum(x > 20 & !is.na(x))+1))
df1$interaction
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1
```